# why std::sort() requires static Compare function?

Tags: c++, std

I am solving a problem in Leetcode OJ. I wrote a solution like this:

```
/**
 * Definition for an interval.
 * struct Interval {
 *     int start;
 *     int end;
 *     Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
 *     Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    bool comparefunc (const Interval& a, const Interval& b) {
        return a.start < b.start;
    }
    vector<Interval> merge(vector<Interval> &intervals) {
        vector<Interval> result;
        if(intervals.empty()) return result;

        // sort Interval vector on increasing order of start
        sort (intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), comparefunc);

        // some other stuffs
        result.push_back(intervals[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < intervals.size(); ++i) {
            if(intervals[i].start > result.back().end) result.push_back(intervals[i]);
            else result.back().end = max(result.back().end, intervals[i].end);
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

And this yields compilation error:

```
    no matching function for call to 
'sort(std::vector<Interval>::iterator, std::vector<Interval>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

Then I changed the `comparefunc` signature with `static`(saw in other's solution) like:

```
static bool comparefunc (const Interval& a, const Interval& b) {
    return a.start < b.start;
}
```

And it worked! My question is - why it needs to be `static`?

Comment: Because non-static member functions have an implicit 1st parameter for `this`. That is how they access other members.

Comment: @juanchopanza some more explanation please! Please post an answer

Comment: For the same reason that outside of a member function of `Solution`, you cannot call a non-static function `comparefunc` without specifying an instance of `Solution`. That is, `Solution::comparefunc(a, b)` is not syntactically valid. `&Solution::comparefunc` is a "pointer-to-member-function" (see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html, for example).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Think of how you call `compareFunc` outside of the class. You always would have something like

```
a.compareFunc(b, c)
^             ^  ^
```

which is 3 parameters, not 2.

`sort`'s code is outside your class and would have to use the syntax above.

Making the member static allows this call:

```
Solution::compareFunc(a, b)
```

which is only 2 parameters and matches the predicate `std::sort` expects.

This is why (for example) when you overload `operator<` as a member function it accepts one parameter, whereas if you overload it as a nonmember, it requires two:

```
struct Foo
{
    bool operator<(Foo const& other) { /* ... */ }
};

int main()
{
    Foo a, b;
    a < b; // calls a.operator<(b)
}
```

versus

```
struct Foo
{};

bool operator<(Foo const& lhs, foo const& rhs) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    Foo a, b;
    a < b; // calls operator<(a, b)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

without `static`, `&Solution::comparefunc`'s type is:

```
bool (Solution::*) (const Interval& a, const Interval& b);
```

with `static`, `&Solution::comparefunc`'s type is:

```
bool (*) (const Interval& a, const Interval& b);
```